# Python программа автозапуск

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Есть программа написанная на python, какие строки кода нужно добавить, чтобы она всегда запускалась и работала при старте ОС Windos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import getpass
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```

Добавьте этот код в ваш исходник. Данный код создает .bat файл, в котором запускается ваш скрипт. Сам .bat файл располагается в папке Startup, в которой находятся приложения для автозапуска при старте системы.